# Changing color for grid lines markers in Coreplot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I need to remove the grid line markers which are basically an extension of the major and minor grid lines on my graph (set to gray color). I need to make both these colors consistent. I am not able to find the necessary attribute to set. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here. I cannot attach images to better depict my problem. Please feel free to ask any follow up questions and I'll clarify. Thanks in advance!

Below is my code so far:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle;
// Grid line styles
majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

// Axises (X & Y)
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a gray `CPTColor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CPTColor`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_color.html) defines the same basic colors as `UIColor`, including `+lightGrayColor` and `+darkGrayColor`.

If those don't meet your needs, you can use `+colorWithGenericGray:` to make any gray between black and white or `+colorWithComponentRed:green:blue:alpha:` to make any RGB color including those with transparency.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your response. I understand the features and attributes you are mentioning. Let me try to rephrase my question:
When I change the color of the major grid lines, lets say to light gray, the color only changes till it touches the x-axis from the graph space. However, the color of the small line from the x-axis below the graph space (which is next to the tick locations/label) is still black! I cannot find a way to change that to grey. OR is there a way to remove them? 

Is there a way I can send u a snapshot and explain this better as I am unable to upload an image here.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem. Since I had labeling policy none for my labels on the x-axis and since I was rotating them and presenting it on the screen, the small line below the plot area (extension of the major grid lines I mentioned above) also got rotated. My intention was ONLY to rotate the label and NOT the line. To fix this I just commented out the below line:
CPTAxisLabel *newLabel;
newLabel.rotation = M_PI/8;
Having said that, it would be nice to know if there is a way to decouple these things.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the tick marks on the axis. Use the `majorTickLineStyle` for major ticks and `minorTickLineStyle` for the minor tick marks. Set a line style (can be the same as the grid lines or different for contrast) or `nil` if you don't want any tick marks.